# How to insert datetime like (2019-03-01 24:30:15) from excel file in database while inserting using PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm using xampp server and trying to insert data of large excel file with PHPEXCEL. but it store only date not time like(2019-03-01 00:00:00).

This is the [link](https://www.webslesson.info/2016/03/read-excel-data-and-insert-into-mysql-database-using-php.html) where I found this code.

```
$datetime= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());

$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());

$query = "INSERT INTO test(datetime,email) VALUES ('".$datetime."', '".$email."')";
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: How is the column in your database defined? Based on your description of the problem it sounds like it is defined as `date` instead of `datetime`.

Comment: in database i use `datetime` datatype and i also try `timestamp` datatype.but not working.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($datetime);` before the query and make sure it contains what you are expecting. Based on your description of the problem it seems likely that it will not contain what you think it should.